# jquery mobile popup not working (for loop)?

Tags: jquery-mobile, for-loop, popup

I tried to create pop ups using for-loop, but does not work. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/edgardaraujo/Rud3G/2/

I thank you all for the help.

```
content html

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="output"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
</div>


content jquery

var array = new Array();

array[0] = "link-image-1";
array[1] = "link-image-2";
array[2] = "link-image-3";
var len = Object.keys(array).length;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    var popup = array[i];

    $('#output').css({'font-weight': 'bold'}).append('<a href="#' + popup + '" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade"><img class="popphoto" src="' + popup + '" alt="photo, test" style="width:30%"></a>');

    var arrayPhotos = $('<div data-role="popup" id="' + popup + '" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d" data-corners="false"></div>');

    arrayPhotos.append('<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>   <img class="popphoto" src="' + popup + '" style="max-height:512px;" alt="photo, test">');

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: create a gallery of images as in this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/edgardaraujo/Rud3G/2/

Comment: see this version http://jsfiddle.net/edgardaraujo/Rud3G/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Upadate

When you create `[data-role=popup]` dynamically, you need to enhance its markup by using `.trigger('create')`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UbnVh/)**

---

You have a mistake in `href` of the link to popup. You have used variable `popup` which holds image links instead of using the count variable `i`.

> href="#popup' + i + '"

Here

```
$('#output').css({ 'font-weight': 'bold'}).append('<a href="#popup' + i + '" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade"><img class="popphoto" src="' + popup + '" alt="photo, test" style="width:30%"></a>');
```

And

```
var arrayPhotos = $('<div data-role="popup" id="popup' + i +'" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d" data-corners="false"></div>');
```

Comment: The for-loop is not working with the array containing the image links.
You associated with the links that are in html.
Here is my problem with the for-loop.
jsfiddle.net/edgardaraujo/Rud3G/2

Comment: I examined your code and it unfortunately did not help me, but thank you.

Comment: @Edgard check this and let me know if you need further help http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UbnVh/

Comment: great alternative, congratulations.
But I could not understand what the error in the for-loop I did?
Could you clarify?

Comment: @Edgard the problem isn't in the loop, it's the way you appended the items. In the demo I merged popup divs with their images and then used `create` to enhance their markup.